# Eliminar duplicados en un array de objetos en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un array de objetos y quería saber si hay alguna manera de eliminar los duplicados.
`array_unique()` no lo detecta.

La solución que me funciona es recorrerlo, sacar `["tagname"]` a otro array, eliminar los duplicados guardando su índice y, posteriormente, eliminar del array de objetos los elementos con ese índice.
Pero esto sería dar demasiadas vueltas a un objeto que va a contener 100k+ elementos.

¿Conocéis algo más óptimo?

¡Gracias!

**var_dump del array de objetos**

```
array(15) {
  [0]=>
  [...]
  [10]=>
  object(stdClass)#12 (2) {
    ["tagname"]=>
    string(12) "REPEATED_TAG"
    ["category"]=>
    string(7) "DEFAULT"
  }
  [11]=>
  object(stdClass)#13 (2) {
    ["tagname"]=>
    string(4) "TEST"
    ["category"]=>
    string(7) "DEFAULT"
  }
  [14]=>
  object(stdClass)#16 (2) {
    ["tagname"]=>
    string(12) "REPEATED_TAG"
    ["category"]=>
    string(7) "DEFAULT"
  }
  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El propio Php , ya tiene una función encargada de eso.

```
array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
```

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)
[Documentacion](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: Te amo @CodeNoob

Comment: El caso es que ya había leído la documentación, pero con la frase "SORT_REGULAR - compara ítems normalmente (no cambia los tipos)" no me había quedado nada claro!

Comment: Se agradecen los cumplidos. Pero estamos para ayudarnos entre todos y crear una mejor comunidad.

Answer (score 3):

si te sirve este código:

```
function super_unique($array,$key)

{

$temp_array = array();

foreach ($array as &$v) {

   if (!isset($temp_array[$v[$key]]))

   $temp_array[$v[$key]] =& $v;

}

$array = array_values($temp_array);

return $array;



}
```

Cortesía de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php

Funciona de la siguiente manera:
super_unique($array, $parametro a filtrar);

Answer (score -1):

Aqui dejo una función para eliminar los duplicados de un array ya sea de tipo simple, objetos o multidimensional:

```
// Elimino duplicados de un array sin importar su tipo. Si $keys es array vacio lo trato como de tipo simple
function eliminarDuplicados(array $array, array $keys = [], $idem = true): array
{
  // Comparo los valores e identifico que operador de desigualdad usar
  $comparar = function ($a, $b, $key) use ($idem) {
    if ($idem) {
      return getValor($a, $key) !== getValor($b, $key);
    }
    return getValor($a, $key) != getValor($b, $key);
  };

  // Itero sobre las diferentes $keys y para determinar la duplicidad
  $determinarDuplicidad = function ($a, $b) use ($keys, $comparar) {
    return array_reduce(
      $keys,
      fn ($acumulador, $key) => ($acumulador === null ? $comparar($a, $b, $key) : $acumulador) || $comparar($a, $b, $key)
    );
  };

  // Itero para y voy eliminado los duplicados usando un criterio de filtro definido por $keys
  return array_reduce(
    $array,
    fn ($acumulador, $valor) => array_merge(
      array_filter(
        $acumulador,
        fn ($valor_filter) => $determinarDuplicidad($valor_filter, $valor)
      ),
      [$valor]
    ),
    []
  );
}

// Esta es la implementacion de getValor que uso dentro de eliminarDuplicados()
// Devuelvo el valor segun el tipo (array, objeto o simple)
function getValor($valor, $key = null)
{
  switch (gettype($valor)) {
    case 'object':
      return $valor->{$key};
    case 'array':
      return $valor[$key];
    default:
      return $valor;
  }
}
```

Comment: No dejes link fuera del sitio para mostrar una respuesta.

Comment: @RamiroBarone ya está corregido, gracias por el consejo