# Eliminar duplicado Array php

Tags: php, array

Tengo un array de esta forma:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [iataCity] => NRT
            [nameCity] => Tokyo
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [iataCity] => MIA
        [nameCity] => Miami
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [iataCity] => DFW
        [nameCity] => Dallas
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [iataCity] => LAX
        [nameCity] => Los Angeles
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [iataCity] => MIA
        [nameCity] => Miami
    )
```

)

Se repite Miami, la idea es que ninguna ciudad se repita, he tratado con array_unique pero no funciona.

He usado los siguientes:

```
array_unique($flightScales, SORT_REGULAR);
array_unique($flightScales);
array_values(array_unique($flightScales));
```

¿Alguna otra idea?

Comment: por favor muestranos como estas usando `array_unique()`

Comment: @shadow listo, ya lo edite

Comment: Revisa aquí, parece que tienen el mismo problema y también han usado array_unique(). https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98483/eliminar-duplicados-en-un-array-de-objetos-en-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El detalle es que tienes un array de array (multidimensional), para eliminar un elemento repetido que en este caso es un array usa lo siguinete:

```
 $sinReperir = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $flightScales)));
//imprime resultado
print_r($sinReperir);
```